# oracle function not returning correct value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this function  which data from select needs to compare with conditions i made in IF and it works in case when i have one row in select,  then it returns ret_val = 0.

But if there are two or more rows which one of them fulfills condition  and one does not,  still it doesn't return 0 ,it returns rec_tkt_sess.cash_out.

Can someone tell why cursor in IF doesn't return 0 with these data bellow?

Like it cursor does not go through IF with all rows...

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cash_out_ticket_cond(party_id   IN casino_users.party_id%TYPE ,session_id IN bus_session.session_id%TYPE    

    ) RETURN NUMBER AS ret_val NUMBER; 

    P_EXCHANGE_BET_CREDITS COUNTRY.EXCHANGE_BET_CREDITS%type;
    P_EXCHANGE_VALUE    COUNTRY.EXCHANGE_VALUE%type;


CURSOR cur_tkt_sess (party_id IN casino_users.party_id%TYPE,session_id IN .bus_session.session_id%TYPE)
        IS
        SELECT bs.session_id 
                ,tii.status 
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bs.session_id ORDER BY status ASC)  rn 
                ,NVL(TO_CHAR(bs.started, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'), 'Live')  started 
                ,bs.bet  bet 
                ,tii.time_p 
                ,tii.live_prematch 
                ,cash_out(bet)  cash_out 
            FROM bus_session bs 
                ,ticket_items tii 
        WHERE bs.session_id             = tii.bus_session_session_id 
            AND bs.session_type         = 'TICKET SESSION' 
            AND bs.party_id             = cur_tkt_sess.party_id 
            AND bs.session_id           = cur_tkt_sess.session_id 
            AND NVL(bs.session_close, 'N') = 'N';           
    rec_tkt_sess cur_tkt_sess%ROWTYPE; 

    BEGIN       
        CHAGE_CREDITS (party_id, P_EXCHANGE_BET_CREDITS, P_EXCHANGE_VALUE);     
    OPEN cur_tkt_sess(cash_out_ticket_cond.party_id, cash_out_ticket_cond.session_id); 
            FETCH cur_tkt_sess 
    INTO rec_tkt_sess; 

    IF(cur_tkt_sess%FOUND) THEN         
        IF( 
            (TO_DATE(rec_tkt_sess.started,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') +1 <=SYSDATE)  -- is ticket older then 24 hours
            OR 
            (rec_tkt_sess.live_prematch != '0')  --is it live  (1 live , 0 not live)
            OR 
            (rec_tkt_sess.time_p <SYSDATE)  -- is game begin
            )
            THEN 
                ret_val := 0;
            ELSE 
            ret_val := rec_tkt_sess.cash_out;           
        END IF; 

    ELSE    
        ret_val := -1; 
    END IF; 

    RETURN(ret_val); 

    END cash_out_ticket_cond;
```

Comment: Because `rec_tkt_sess.time_p <SYSDATE` is true

Comment: Yes in  1st row, but in 2ND its false..

Comment: Why use cursor? Why you can't put in one SQL statement? And why you don't close cursor?

Comment: I closed it now, it didnt even report me the error for it. 
How will i put it in one, where there could be more than 2 games to check it through IF..

Comment: So, lets say, it finds more than 1, what you need to show? ret_val = -1? Raise exception?

Comment: if it finds at least one row which fulfills condition then return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only FETCHING one row and without having an ORDER BY clause you have no idea which of your two sample rows will be FETCHED.  After adding ORDER BY, cycle through the results until you reach the condition you are looking for:

```
OPEN cur_tkt_sess;
LOOP
    FETCH cur_tkt_sess INTO rec_tkt_sess;
    EXIT WHEN cur_tkt_sess%NOTFOUND;
    --[ Check some stuff, Do some stuff ]--
END LOOP
CLOSE cur_tkt_sess
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I ordered by time_p and it fetching the first game ... Thanks